# javascript - Get datauri from URL images (Synchronous XMLHttpRequest blob requests)

Tags: javascript, image, jspdf, data-uri

I'm generating a PDF document using [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf), however I need to add the images submitted in the form into this document.

```
// You'll need to make your image into a Data URL
// Use http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/2wBDAQICAgICAg[...]' //snip
[...]
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160)
```

However, as shown in the snip above I need to convert the file to DataURI, but I haven't found a library that does this, nor a reliable way to do it with pure JavaScript.

I found the following method that allows me to extract the DataURI from an URL with XMLHttpRequest.

```
function obtenerDataUri(url, pos, lastpos, isleft) 
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    request.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
        reader.onload = function(e){
            var imgData = e.target.result.replace("data:application/xml;", "data:application/png;"), pos, lastpos, isleft;
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', (isleft) ? 15 : 90, (isleft) ? pos : lastpos, 75, 75);
        };
    };
    request.send();
}
```

This method doesn't work for me because it's asynchronous, it means I'm adding the content in the PDF after it's fully generated. This method doesn't work synchronously because `responseType` is not supported in synchronous requests(probably due the deprecation).

Note that these images are already uploaded to the server when the PDF is ready to be generated, so I can't get the DataURIs on local files.

This function is called from here:

```
$('#imgArea img').each(function()
{
  g_bPDFGisLeft = !g_bPDFGisLeft;
  var bPDFGposCheck = true;
    while(bPDFGposCheck)
    {
      var pos = (g_iPDFGpage == 0) ? doc.autoTable.previous.finalY+8+(75*g_iPDFGimg) : (75*g_iPDFGimg);
      if((pos+(75*(g_iPDFGimg+1))) >= 300)
      {
        doc.addPage();
        g_iPDFGimg = 0;
        g_iPDFGpage++;
        bPDFGposCheck = true;
      }
      else
        bPDFGposCheck = false;
    }

    obtenerDataUri($(this).attr('src'), pos, g_fPDFGlastPos, g_bPDFGisLeft);

    g_fPDFGlastPos = pos;
    if(!g_bPDFGisLeft)
      g_iPDFGimg++;
});
```

After executing `obtenerDataUri`, due the fact it's doing a request, won't wait until the `onload` function completes. This mean the PDF generator will keep adding pages and placing the images asynchronously in the incorrect pages.

How can I get the DataURI in a synchronous way from URL images?

I appreciate any help with this issue. Please tell me if you need more details about this.

Comment: No experience with filereader, but curious. It looks like filereader gets the file by itself, so why wrap it inside an ajax call? And if reader.onload passes the filedata into the callback handler then you can put the doc.addImage inside that handler ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

Comment: Ah, looks like filereader can't get a file from the server???

Answer (score 0):

Don't return result. Instead pass it to a callback function:

```
function obtenerDataUrl(url) 
{
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.responseType = 'blob';
  request.onload = function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(request.response);
      reader.onload = function(e){
          //return e.target.result;
          handleResult(e.target.result);
      };
  };
  request.send();
}

function handleResult(result) {
    var imgData = result; // or take whatever you need inside result
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't accept your answer. `handleResult` is asyncronous, meaning it will add images into the PDF after `addPage`(not shown in the snippet) has been called several times so the images will be in the incorrect pages (this is just an example of what's happening).

Comment: `handleResult` itself is not asynchronous, maybe you mean it's being called asynchronously, or `doc.addImage` is asynchronous? Anyway, maybe you should edit the question to include `addPage` code to make it a [mcve]

Comment: I edited the question to include the context where this is executed.

Comment: Hmm. You'd have to make synchronous ajax requests. For filereader probably need to use [FilereaderSync](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-FileReaderSync). Otherwise you'd need to write some logic to first fetch imgData for all images, store it in an array (or object so you can add some references), then when all complete call a function where you start creating your doc. Sorry I can't be of more help at this time. Maybe the guys at jsPDF can help you...

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. Also if images are submitted via a form, then maybe you can catch that data when the user uploads them??

Comment: Sadly there are no forms involved, since the images are already submitted way before the PDF generation is available to the user. I worked around it by fetching the data URIs using PHP (and sending the image URLs in GET), then forcing a regular XMLHttpRequest to the PHP file to be synchronous. Asides from the console warning about deprecation it worked as I expected. It's not pretty but it should work by now. (You can't set `request.responseType` on syncronous requests)